# How to coordinate active fonts so that they'll appear in a web page?

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, fonts

I have a case where I've got an old web page with some ancient languages with some older fonts that are being used and the fonts don't appear to be embedded properly and I'd like to render the page such that it shows the proper fonts that it is requesting.

In this case, I have the following example of code in the html:

```
<span style="font-size:24.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:10.0pt;
    font-family:Phoinike;color:blue">EXAMPLE<o:p></o:p></span>
```

I also currently have the font `phoinike.ttf` active and showing in macOS Font Book as Phoinike Regular:

[image: phoinike]

I have some other languages that have the seeming exact same scenario and I have inserted the fonts and they are rendering perfectly (for example, some Egyptian Hieroglyphics, etc.), yet no matter what I do here, this particular font in both Chrome, Safari and Firefox are not rendering.

Any ideas on what one can do to help the browser / HTML renderer to understand that it can use certain fonts when all appearances are seeming to lead to the font being active?  I'm having to believe that somehow the names are different in some way that the renderer uses to properly detect the font, but I'm drawing a blank...

Comment: Browsers have changed in how they display fonts. It used to be that with any font, whenever they had to display an 'A' for example, they simply output the character with index 65 into the font. These days, they check if the font contains the 'A' glyph, and if not, the 'A' will be displayed in the default font.

Comment: So... your task is to find out which glyph in the font corresponds to the character you want to see, and to output the Unicode code point of that glyph. Yes, for each and every separate character in the output.

Comment: Unfortunately that will be an impossible task given that there are quite a few different fonts and therefore a boatload of characters.  Perhaps using a virtual machine with an older operating system and therefore browser would be "easier" than a remapping of the glyphs...

Comment: And so if the virtual machine methodology would be cleanest given this scenario, the question is begged: which operating system and which version(s) were the last to support this?  Or is bound to the browser version(s) and therefore at what version did the "main" browsers stop doing this? Is there a way to find this out readily? I would have to think there's probably a rough cutoff year at the very least when this came into practice...

Comment: You can answer that question yourself. You know that the website is old, and that it worked as designed when it was new. So when was that? Or, you may be able to find info on the web if you search for the history of the Symbol font. It used to be that outputting "abc" with the Symbol font would display "αβγ". So search for when that changed.

Comment: Good question, I'll do some digging and see if I can pull up the old site (which doesn't exist now) vs using an archive of it stored locally.  Archive.org is having some troubles it appears as well.  I'm thinking it was 2008'ish, but not yet certain.  Was hopeful that you had an idea of when the browser practice changed as you note.